# Best Way To Track Transaction Volume Sent to a Ethereum Smart Contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm fairly new to smart contract development. I am looking for what is the best approach to track total volume sent to a smart contract. The options I have found are;

1. Emit an event when a transaction with value is sent to the contract
   and use ethers.js to filter and aggregate all these events to get
   total lifetime volume?
2. Create a mapping in the smart contract which increments every time a value is sent to the contract?

What would be the best to get this data. The first approach with events would give me the ability to filter on timespans. Does anyone have insight what's the best approach or if there is a better way than the above two.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options

First:

you can create variable and add into this variable the value of the transaction and when you need to know all value just return this variable

Second :

If you want to track the volume in real time you can add event listing on this event  and then add the result into your db every time someone interact

Third:

you can make queries filtration on the event and callculat all volume

Comment: So the two ways I mentioned are good?

Comment: The first yes but the second insted of mapping just make uint256 variable